# Upgraded db from 11.2.0.3.0 to 12.1.0.2.0. Slow Journal Import

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-ebs

We upgraded our database from 11.2.0.3.0 to 12.1.0.2.0 on PROD on weekend of 18/19 June 2016.

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;
```

**Version info:**

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.2.0    Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

We are running Oracle Release 12.1.3

We also applied CPU patches and others (13942692, 18813637, 12404574, 15969020, 18835102, 21612876, 17889841, 12598630, 18991480, 22465286, 22614470, 16289505, 18039691, 9833058,, 16958896, 22378313).

During the testing we hit an issue with slow performance of the "**Journal Import**" GLLEZL job.

We find that when the Journal Import runs slowly (e.g. for a 19,000 line Web ADI journal the "Web ADI - Journal Import" job takes 2.5 hours compared to a couple of minutes on the Database 11 version).

For other jobs, e.g. when we load data into the GL_INTERFACE and run a standard "Program - Journal Import", e.g. a 120,000 line journal, the job never completes.

I raised a Service Request and we got a quick fix, which is to cancel the long-running job, and then run this command:

```
exec fnd_stats.gather_table_stats('GL','GL_INTERFACE',100)
```

Then when we re-run the Journal Import it runs quickly.

The strange thing is that we can run that command, and re-run Jnl Import, and the issue is fixed for that instance.

The next time we run a big job, it gets stuck again.

We have reviewed this Note:

**R12: Improving Performance of General Ledger and Journal Import (Doc ID 858725.1)**

We also had another fix from Oracle, which was to:

1. Cancel an unwanted Index on Segment1 of our Accounting Flexfield
2. Run "Program - Optimizer" with both parameters set to Yes
3. Run "Gather Schema Statistics" for GL Schema with 25 as Estimate Percent value

But that has not fixed the problem - we still need to run the manual fix each time.

We also now schedule "Program - Optimizer" with both parameters set to Yes on a daily basis, and a full Gather Schema Stats runs weekly at 25 for all Schemas.

Oracle are still trying to work this one out, but I thought I'd ask here in case anyone else has had similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I worked this out.

Instead of step 3 being:

**Run "Gather Schema Statistics" for `GL` Schema with 25 as Estimate Percent value**

It should be:

**Run "Gather Schema Statistics" for `ALL` Schemas with 25 as Estimate Percent value**

That seemed to do the trick.